# c# update cached object without updating cache

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, caching

I have a model that I am retrieving from a cache, which I use on several pages.  Part of the model has a property called Breadcrumb - which is a collection of breadcrumb elements and is updated like this:

```
model.Breadcrumbs.Add(UrlUtilities.Urls.DesignerJoinConfirmation, "Feedback Confirmation", "Thank you for your feedback");
```

My problem is that even though I am getting the model back from the cache, when I add another breadcrumb after it is returned from the cache (eg for child pages I would add the latest page onto the end), it is then updating the cached model.  Is there a way of updating the model and not updating the cache?

I have tried creating a temp model and reassigning the cached object to it like so:

```
Model model = GetCachedModel();
Model tempModel = new Model();
tempModel = model;
```

And then updating the tempModel but this also updates the cached object.  The only way I have found to stop the cache object being updated is by making the tempModel and then reassigning each property separately from the cached model but surely this negates the need for caching if I have to reassign all the properties each time.  Is there a simpler way to update a cached object without updating the cache itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing references to objects with the objects. When you retrieve the model from the cache you are really only getting another reference to the same object that the cache is referencing. Thus any changes made via your reference will also be visible via any other references.

There are two approaches to avoiding this:

1. Clone—copy—the model instance from the cache. This will require assistance from the implementation to do in general. Remember this will need to be a deep copy, any properties and fields of the model that are themselves references will also need the referenced object to be copied. Recursively.
2. Don't put the breadcrumbs in the model. If difference uses of the same model need different values for this property then it does not belong in the model.

(There are also options using value types—which are copied rather than referenced—but good practice is (1) vale types should be small (not many fields), and (2) immutable.)

> ```
> Model model = GetCachedModel();
> Model tempModel = new Model();
> tempModel = model;
> ```

That's not going to work. You are creating a reference to a new instance (`tempModel`) and then overwriting that reference with a reference to the original from the cache.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't create the objects (or decide to cache them).  I decided to go the cloning route